# Link Aggregation with ESXi 4.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, bonding

I am trying to setup Link Aggregation between a switch and an ESXi 4.1 host.  When I perform all of the steps I think that I need, the switch shows the ports as being linked and that they have an avtive link state and have negotiated the speed and duplex mode, but I am not able to ping from the ESX host to the gateway or to connect to the ESX host remotely.

Hardware

- Switch: Extream Networks Summit x350-48t ([data sheet](http://www.extremenetworks.com/libraries/products/DSSumX350_1399.pdf))
- host NIC: Intel NC364T Quad Port ([quick-specs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12701_div/12701_div.pdf))
- host Server: HP ProLiant DL380 G5, (2) Xeon E5450, 36 GB RAM

Steps Taken

1. Changed the vSwitch NIC Teaming to Load Balance based to "Route based on IP hash"
2. Created a Link Aggregation Group on the switch by issuing command "enable sharing 1 grouping 1-4" (this sets 1 as the master port, and links ports 1,2,3,4 statically with address-based link aggregation by Layer 2)
3. After viewing the status being reported as expected, ran a ping test from ESX host which failed
4. Rebooted ESX host

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your switch but one gotcha on link aggregation is that it doesn't support LACP auto-negotiation so you have to configure the bonded ports statically on the switch.  On a Cisco this is done by setting "no channel-protocol lacp" and "channel-group # mode on" rather than "channel-group # mode active" which seems to be an old style EtherChannel.

Comment: With these Summit X350's, static is the default.  To get LACP you include it as part of the enable sharing command as the last argument.